The 'width' of a photon, Young's Slits vs. Gravitational lensing
When Young's classic two slit experiment was introduced to me at school, it was not too much of a stretch for me to accept the idea of a photon spreading out sideways to encompass both slits a good fraction of a mm apart, not withstanding the light wavelength was 600 nm.
Idly thinking about gravitational lensing, especially where two images of one remote body form on both sides of an intervening galaxy, I would need to imagine a photon being many, many light years across, which is 'obviously' nonsense. But then, this appears to be just a difference of scale, not a qualitative difference, and I should have been more disturbed by the two slit demonstration.
This seems to make the concept of a photon not actually explain anything to me, or at least modelled as having a location and size, and you might as well simply 'shut up and calculate'. Does the usefulness of a photon model vary with scale?

Gravitational lensing creating two images isn't actually an instance of the two slit effect. In the case of gravitational lensing, imagine a heavy thing (like a black hole or galaxy) between you and an interesting, luminous thing (like a star or other galaxy). Gravitational lensing creates double images of the object from your perspective, not because one photon is getting bent around both sides of the intervening massive object, but because two photons sent to either side of the massive object end up at the same place, your eye, despite being on initially different trajectories. This is due to the fact that photons, affected by gravity, curve around the massive object like the Juice probe just did on its flyby of Earth's moon, and the two (or ten quintillion) different curves happened to land two photons originating from the object of interest in your eye. This is cool for astronomy not because it necessarily gives us a very clear image but because we can then see stuff that's behind other stuff.
Phenomenologically, this is interesting because it demonstrates that massless photons are affected by gravity when Newton's law says they shouldn't be, which is the real question to be asked here. There's no conflict between the results of Young's two-slit experiment and the observation of gravitational lensing; astronomy works mostly fine if you treat photons as point particles rather than the proper quantum wavefunction. This answers your question: at the interstellar scale, modelling photons as wavefunctions becomes just extra work.

I thought gravitational lensing requires sensitive equipment to detect?

Seeing any object massive enough to cause it does; and yes, it does require very sensitive equipment.
